# EF Core - Linq query search contain any in list string error

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
var searchs = new List<string> { "a1", "a2", "a3" };
var result = db.Products.Where(p => searchs.Any(s => p.Content.Contains(s))).ToList();
```

(Content is a string)
This query work fine in asp.net mvc 5
but when i update to vs 2022 with asp.net mvc core .net 6, this query erorr like that

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 's => EntityShaperExpression: 
    Website.Models.Product
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.Content.Contains(s)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

i don't know why, anyone help me, thanks!
sorry my English not good!

I have searched many solutions but still can't find it, I want help

**update: (17 july 2023)**

i see example like my query at this link (Ef 8.0):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew

```
var beers = new[] { "Carling", "Heineken", "Stella Artois", "Carlsberg" };
var pubsWithLager = await context.Pubs
    .Where(e => beers.Any(b => e.Beers.Contains(b)))
    .Select(e => e.Name)
    .ToListAsync();
```

update 01 Dec 2023
i use .net 8 and it doesn't error anymore

Comment: What kind of SQL query are you trying to generate? It matters on two levels -1) `Contains(s)` translates to `LIKE '%s%'` which doesn't work with a list of patterns and 2) `LIKE '%s%`is *very* slow because it can't use indexes. If you want to search for a list of words in a text field, the appropriate solution is to use your database's [Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) functionality to perform Google-like searches, eg `CONTAINS(p.Content, 'A OR B OR C')`

Comment: I want to make a search query, thanks for your idea

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)'s `PredicateBuilder`:

```cs
var predicate = searchs.Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.New<Products>(),
    (e, s) => e.Or(p => p.Content.Contains(s))); // build the predicate

var result = db.Products
    .Where(predicate)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

**You could use a Table Valued Parameter**, which is probably more efficient than lots of parameters (which is what `PredicateBuidler` would do). **Note that this answer only works on SQL Server.**

First create one in your database. I usually keep a few useful single- and two-column ones around for these purposes.

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList AS TABLE (Value nvarchar(100) PRIMARY KEY);
```

Add an extension method to use it

```cs
public static IQueryable<string> ToTvp_StringList(
    this ISet<string> source,
    DbContext context,
    string paramName
)
{
    var table = new DataTable { Columns = {
        {"Value", typeof(string)},
    }};
    var rows = new object[1];  // reuse array for performance
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        rows[0] = item;
        table.Rows.Add(rows);
    }
    var param = new SqlParameter(paramName, SqlDbType.Structured)
    {
        TypeName = "dbo.StringList",
        Value = table,
    };

    // Database.SqlQuery requires the column to always be aliased "Value"
    return context.Database.SqlQueryRaw<string>(
        $"SELECT Value FROM {param.ParameterName}",
        param
    );
}
```

**You can then use it like this:**

```cs
var searchs = new HashSet<string> { "a1", "a2", "a3" };

// do not put the TVP creation inside the other lambda, create it separately
var searchQuery = searchs.ToTvp_StringList(yourDbContext, "@searches");

var result = db.Products
    .Where(p => searchQuery.Contains(p.Content))
    .ToList();
```

If you don't want a unique list then remove `PRIMARY KEY` from the type definition, and change `ISet` to `IEnumerable`.

---

**If you have a multi-column TVP** then you need a mapping type.
Create a mapping type for your `DbContext` model

```cs
public class StringStringList
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Add the class (you don't need this step for the new EF Core version 8+):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<StringStringList>().HasNoKey();  // HasNoKey prevents tracking
```

And call it like this

```cs
public static IQueryable<StringStringList> ToTvp_StringStringList(
    this IEnumerable<(string value1, string value2)> source,
    DbContext context,
    string paramName
)
{
    var table = new DataTable { Columns = {
        {"Value1", typeof(string)},
        {"Value2", typeof(string)},
    }};
    var rows = new object[2];  // reuse array for performance
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        rows[0] = item.value1;
        rows[0] = item.value2;
        table.Rows.Add(rows);
    }
    var param = new SqlParameter(paramName, SqlDbType.Structured)
    {
        TypeName = "dbo.StringStringList",
        Value = table,
    };

    // Use context FromSqlQuery instead
    return context.Set<StringStringList>.FromSqlQueryRaw(
        $"SELECT Value1, Value2 FROM {param.ParameterName}!,
        param
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short version**

Even if it worked that query would be very slow. The fast alternative is to use a Full-Text-Search index on `Content` and use `p.Content CONTAINS 'a OR b OR c'`:

```
var expr=string.Join(searches, " OR ");
var result = db.Products.Where(p => EF.Functions.Contains(p.Content,expr))
                        .ToList();
```

---

It seems the question is trying to generated something like this WHERE clause:

```
p.Content LIKE '%Banana%' OR p.Content LIKE '%Potato%' OR p.Content LIKE '%Tomato%'
```

with this expression `terms.Any(term => p.Content.Contains(term))`.

This has two problems:

- It's not possible to create composite expressions like this
- `LIKE '%s%'` is too slow

**Composite Expressions**

EF Core can't do this and I suspect some of the reasons are that that `IEnumerable<T>.Contains` gets translated to an `IN (@item1, @item2,...)` clause already and the expression is far too limited to justify translation.

Guru Stron's answer shows how to use LINQKit to generate `OR` clauses from a list of *expressions*, not just values.

**Performance**

The other problem is that `LIKE '%Banana%'` can't take advantage of indexes and requires a full table scan to find matches. This can seriously harm performance with large or frequently updated tables.

Databases solve this through Google-like Full-Text-Search indexes and queries. Almost all databases have FTS features. Eg SQL Server's FTS docs [are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16). The question's query could be :

```
WHERE p.Content CONTAINS 'Banana OR Potato OR Tomato'
```

In EF Core over SQL Server, FTS queries can be performed through the [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.contains?view=efcore-7.0) or [FreeText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext?view=efcore-7.0) operations that map to [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [FREETEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) respectively.

If the terms are words, they can be joined into a single FTS expression with `OR`:

```
var expr=string.Join(searches, " OR ");
var result = db.Products.Where(p => EF.Functions.Contains(p.Content,expr))
                        .ToList();
```

Phrases need to be quoted :

```
var expr="'" +  string.Join(searches, "' OR '") +"'";
var result = db.Products.Where(p => EF.Functions.Contains(p.Content,expr))
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Error already suggested a solution. it says 'p.Content.Contains(s)' cannot be translated to a valid database query, try to switch to client evaluation by calling .AsEnumerable().

```
var searchs = new List<string> { "a1", "a2", "a3" };
var result = DatabaseContext.Products.AsEnumerable().Where(p => searchs.Any(s => p.Content.Contains(s))).ToList();
```

By calling AsEnumerable(), you indicate that the subsequent operations should be performed on the client side instead of being translated into a database query. This allows you to use the Contains method within the LINQ expression without causing translation issues.