# EF Core using a Like clause within a collection.any is untranslatable

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to compare a specific column in a database to be a substring of any string in a local collection.

```
var localStringList = new List<string>() { stringA, stringB };

var result = database.table
                     .Where(x => localStringList.Any(y => EF.Functions.Like(x.column, "%" + y + "%")))
```

I get the runtime error that the query is untranslatable.

I cannot use a simple `.Contains`, as I need to have the wildcard support, I also couldn't find any alternative methods to get rid of the `.Any`. I have tried replacing it with a constructed regex as well, which couldn't be translated either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core - Linq query search contain any in list string error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76686494/ef-core-linq-query-search-contain-any-in-list-string-error)

Comment: Use a Table Valued Parameter.

Comment: @Charlieface none of those proposed solution seem like they would work for my case, as I NEED to run the query server side, I am not at liberty to pull in additional dependencies (LINQKit) And the ef.function.contains function seemingly isn't available in the dotnet core/efcore versions the project uses. And TVP aren't a viable solution in this case either, as that'd require creating additional tables, from my understanding of the documentation.

Comment: No they don't require additional tables, you only need to create a table type. `CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList ( Value varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY);` is the only thing you need, and it takes up no space in the database.

Comment: Answered similar question several times - [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73048043/10646316) without third party libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing here most likely is that EF does not know how to translate that into a reasonable SQL expression.

While chaining `and` is rather simple (doing `query = query.Where(...)`), chaining `or` requires more setup:

```cs
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class MyClass
{
    public string Fancy { get; set; }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        DbContext dbContext = null!;
        var list = new List<string> {"%FancyA%", "%FancyB%"};
        var query = dbContext.Set<MyClass>().AsQueryable();
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "x");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, nameof(MyClass.Fancy));
        // Make sure that list is not empty here! Otherwise the expression will be invalid as it will be null
        Expression expression = null!;
        foreach (var s in list)
        {
            var constant = Expression.Constant(s);
            var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions),
                nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like), new[] {typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(string)},
                Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), property, constant);
            if (expression == null)
            {
                expression = methodCallExpression;
            }
            else
            {
                expression = Expression.OrElse(expression, methodCallExpression);
            }
        }

        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, bool>>(expression, parameterExpression);
        query = query.Where(lambdaExpression);
        var results = await query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I do want to note that this is a rather basic sample that can be improved upon (notably: caching the expressions) but that should give you enough to get back to coding again :)

## What is happening here

So first of all, we take create a `IQueryable` and put it into `query`.
After that, we "proceed" as one would normally using EF, but we create the expression tree passed in manually, instead of letting the compiler do it for us.

In the end, we append that expression to our query and get the data.

I highly recommend https://sharplab.io/ to understand how C# lowers your code, giving you a simpler way of writing a lot of theese expression trees :) (JetBrains also offers this in Rider)

Comment: That worked perfectly, except that I had to replace the ` new[] {typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(string)}` with a null, as `DbFunctionsExtensions` doesn't take any generic type parameters.